# Подвисание Task

Tags: c#, wpf, асинхронность

Есть фрагмент кода. отправляет запрос на распознавание капчи и ждет ответа. соответсвенно нужно сделать это одельным потоком. Сделал так:

```
public string send(object state)
{
    string reqest = "";

    captchaID = RC.UploadCaptchaFile("D://loadimage.jpg");

    Task<string> s = new Task<string>(() =>  //Вот тут подвисание Внутри таска, будто в основном потоке цикл
    {
        while (!reqest.Contains("OK|"))
        {
            reqest = capt(reqest);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        return reqest;
    });
    s.Start();
    reqest = s.Result;
    return  = reqest.Replace("OK|", ""); 
}
```

.

```
string capt(string req)
{
    req = HttpRequest.GET_http("http://бла бла + captchaID);
    switch (req)
    {
        //Кейсы с меседжбоксами
    }

    Console.WriteLine(req);
    return req;
}

Сам send вызываю так:

 Task<string> c = new Task<string>(te.send, "D://loadimage.jpg");
 c.Start();
```

Проблема в том, что это не срабатывает и основной поток зависает. Как делать понять не могу.Так же пытался сделать проверку с задержкой с помошью `Task.Delay()` и `Thread.Sleep()` но так только дольше задержка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш код виснет на главном потоке в двух местах

1) `captchaID = RC.UploadCaptchaFile("D://loadimage.jpg");` - тут очень похоже на синхронный вызов

2) `reqest = s.Result;` - тут вы ждете результат в главном потоке

Правильно так

```
    public async Task<string> send(object state)
    {
        return await Task.Run(() => {
            string reqest = "";
            captchaID = RC.UploadCaptchaFile("D://loadimage.jpg");
            while (!reqest.Contains("OK|")) {
                reqest = capt(reqest);
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            return reqest.Replace("OK|", "");
        });
    }
```

То есть если вы хотите выполнить код без блокировки главного потока, то выполняйте его весь внутри Task.Run.